# how can i import txt file in sql with dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic, import

im trying to import txt file with different title in a table. i tried this code, but i know that is wrong.

```
declare @fecha as date
set @fecha = '02/28/2014'
declare @varfecha as varchar(20)
set @varfecha= convert(varchar(20),YEAR(@fecha))+convert(varchar(20),left(right(@fecha,5),2))
declare @sql as varchar(1000)
print @varfecha 

select @sql= 'create table ['+@varfecha+']
(ID varchar(40),
Cierre varchar(40),
  Seg1 float,
Mora1 float,
Saldo_Tarshop float,
Saldo_FD float,
Seg2 float,
Mora2 float)

bulk insert ['+@varfecha+']
from C:\Martin\T\201403\Archivos Recibidos\'+@varfecha+'.txt
WITH
( 
FIELDTERMINATOR = |,
ROWTERMINATOR = |
 )'
exec(@sql)
```

i think that the error could be inverted commas in the bulk insert, becuse when i tried the following code, works perfect:

```
declare @fecha as date
set @fecha = '07/31/2014'
declare @varfecha as varchar(20)
set @varfecha= convert(varchar(20),YEAR(@fecha))+convert(varchar(20),left(right(@fecha,5),2))
declare @sql as varchar(1000)
select @sql= 'create table ['+@varfecha+']
(ID varchar(40),
Cierre varchar(40),
Seg1 float,
Mora1 float,
Saldo_Tarshop float,
Saldo_FD float,
Seg2 float,
Mora2 float)'
 exec(@sql)
```

what can i do?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
bulk insert ['+@varfecha+']
from 'C:\Martin\T\201403\Archivos Recibidos\' + @varfecha + '.txt'
```

instead of:

```
bulk insert ['+@varfecha+']
from C:\Martin\T\201403\Archivos Recibidos\'+@varfecha+'.txt
```

Comment: when i put that code, appears the following error message:                                                                    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 56
        Incorrect syntax near '\'.

Comment: What does the entire string contain? 'C:\Martin\T\201403\Archivos Recibidos\' + @ varfecha + '.txt' Does the variable contain a valid path to the file?

Comment: Also, it might be balking at concatenating the query string inline while executing the BULK INSERT statement. Try adding your entire BULK INSERT command it to a variable and then executing like you're doing with @sql. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234841/sql-server-msg-102-level-15-state-1-line-2-incorrect-syntax-near

Answer (score 0):

Without the actual error, its difficult to diagnose but generally, these are the types of errors you could encounter:
1. Is the data in the txt file formatted according to the data types used in the table in the same order? If not, you need to convert the data into the correct format before insertion.
2. You might not have permission to access the file from the path yo umentioned from SQL Server 
3. Is the separator used in your query the same one in the file [you mention '|' as the row  terminator. Is that supposed to be ' |\n'
4. The syntax for bulk insert is as follows:

```
 declare @fecha as date
set @fecha = '02/28/2014'
declare @varfecha as varchar(20)
set @varfecha= convert(varchar(20),YEAR(@fecha))+convert(varchar(20),left(right(@fecha,5),2))
declare @sql as varchar(1000)
print @varfecha 

select @sql= 'create table ['+@varfecha+']
(ID varchar(40),
Cierre varchar(40),
  Seg1 float,
Mora1 float,
Saldo_Tarshop float,
Saldo_FD float,
Seg2 float,
Mora2 float)

bulk insert ['+@varfecha+']
from ''C:\Martin\T\201403\Archivos Recibidos\'+@varfecha+'.txt''
WITH
( 
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',
ROWTERMINATOR = ''|\n'' )'
exec(@sql)
```

You seem to be missing the quotes.

Again, without actual error messages, it is difficult to resolve issues like these.